# IN clause not working in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I have a query which uses IN clause and it is not working for below case:

```
Select *   
from table1   
where   
Rollno || '/' || UserId IN ('1/001,2/002')
```

Comment: What is not working? Errors, no data, runs for hours? Specify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because you haven't wrapped each value in single quotes `'` :

```
SELECT *   
FROM table1   
WHERE  Rollno || '/' || UserId IN ('1/001','2/002')
```

Comment: I am using this in a report where data is coming from front-end. So you mean i have to split my text and then add quotes to each ?

Comment: @user1630575: Yes, you have to do this. If you are doing this from php you can `explode` your string with `,` delimiter and then `implode` output like `"'" . implode("',",explode(",",$input)) . "'";`

Comment: And if SSRS reports ?

Comment: @user1630575 : There should be a way to split a string with the delimiter and then merge parts in one string with another delimiter. But of course you should do it, otherwise you database will always look for a string like `1/001,2/002`.

Comment: But doesn't comma implement in IN clause that it should be treated as separate entities ?

Comment: @user1630575 : Yes, it should, but you are wrapping the whole string in the single quotes, so it is treated like a one string. However, you should wrap each value from the list in the single quotes. So the only way to achieve what you want is to format this string correctly before inserting it in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Notulysses has the right syntax for `in`.  But, if you have to deal with a string, you can rephrase this as `like`:

```
where ',' || Rollno || '/' || UserId || ',' like '%,' || '1/001,2/002' || ',%'
```

`like` is a better approach.  Sometimes in the real world, you might have to deal with comma-delimited strings.

Comment: Why ',' in like clause?? In this situation, like clause doesnt seem appropriate!!

Comment: @Nisha . . . What is your point?  There is a list that has a comma in it.  You can use `like` to find elements of that list.  `in` is definitely better if you can construct the query correctly (as I note), but sometimes you might have to use `like` for this type of situation.

Comment: But in the query that has been asked, i think Notulysses solution would be more appropriate and that like operator would only over-complicate it.

Comment: @Nisha . . . Then you should upvote that answer (as I have).  The OP doesn't say why there is a single string in the `in` clause.  Perhaps there is a reason for that, and `like` would be more appropriate than `in` (doubtful in this situation given that the other answer has since been accepted).  Personally, I don't think downvoting this answer (which is also correct) is appropriate, but there are definitely worse abuses of downvotes.